# Getting the type for a "recursive generic"?

Tags: c#, generics, typeof

I do have a class, which is defined as:

```
public abstract class Singleton <T> : BaseObject
    where T : Singleton <T>
{
}
```

I want to define an array of those generic singletons somewhere else. Something like

```
public MonoSingleton[] singletons;
```

How can I retrieve the proper type of that generic (that seems to be recursive, as you may see)? How can I write this out?

Comment: Using reflection with generic types is extremely complicated.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Writing a generic singleton. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton (last code snippet, at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Show us the code you're trying to write; your question is still unclear.

Comment: @SLaks I've tried to better explain what's my problem. If you want some more code, I'll edit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do the 'curiously recursive template pattern', like this?

```
class CuriouslyRecursiveBase<T>
{

}

class CuriouslyRecursiveDervied<T> : CuriouslyRecursiveBase<T>
{

}

class MyClass : CuriouslyRecursiveBase<MyClass>
{

}
```

To instantiate the derived from the base, you just use:

```
class CuriouslyRecursiveBase<T>
{
    public static void InstantiateDerived()
    {
        T instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Since T is actually the derived type (`MyClass`) and curiously is also type (`CuriouslyRecursive<MyClass>`).

Specifically applied to your problem:

```
// Create a common interface that all singletons use. This allows 
// us to add them all to a list.
interface ISingleton { }

class Singleton<T> : ISingleton
{
    // Store our list of ISingletons
    static List<ISingleton> instances = new List<ISingleton>();
    static T instance;

    protected Singleton() { }

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        // Either return the existing instnace, or create a new one
        if (Singleton<T>.instance == null)
        {
            Singleton<T>.instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            // Use a common interface so they can all be stored together.
            // Avoids the previously mentioned co-variance problem.
            // Also, compiler isn't built to follow curious recursiveness,
            // so use a dynamic statement to force runtime re-evaluation of 
            // the type hierarchy. Try to avoid dynamic statements in general
            // but in this case its useful.
            instances.Add((dynamic)Singleton<T>.instance);
        }

        return Singleton<T>.instance;
    }
}

class MyClass : Singleton<MyClass>
{

}

public static void Main()
{
    MyClass my = MyClass.GetInstance();
}
```

More info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Looks similar, but I'm doing this so that whenever I subclass this, doing `Manager : Singleton<Manager>`, I can instantiate `Manager` from within Singleton.

Comment: Edited. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I want to have a list of all of my created singletons (i.e. an array of `Singleton`s). How do I define that? Is it possible?

Comment: Edited again. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Actually, you know what. If you change the `(dynamic)` cast to a `(ISingleton)` it works fine, and you can get rid of the dynamic, since dynamic is inherently not type-safe (double bonus!).

Answer (score 1):

Using design-time code, you'll be able to get the type by using the `typeof` operator and giving some argument to the generic parameter:

```
typeof(Singleton<SomeImplementationOfBaseObject>)
```

Or

```
typeof(Singleton<>)
```

But there's an alternative: reflection.

```
Type singletonType = Type.GetType("NamespaceA.NamespaceN.Singleton`1");
```

The 1 part is the number of generic parameters. If you've something like `Class<T, S>` it would be 2 and so on.

Note that using reflection *you don't need to give the generic argument*. You can get the type with the generic parameter anyway. In order to give the generic argument, you would do this:

```
Type genericType = singletonType.MakeGenericType(typeof(SomeImplementationOfBaseObject));
```

Or if you want to get it directly, you would do this:

```
Type singletonType = Type.GetType("NamespaceA.NamespaceN.Singleton`1[[NamespaceA.NamespaceN.SomeImplementationOfBaseObject]]");
```

The string inside `[[ ]]` its the full name for the type passed as generic argument. Note that if the generic type isn't the same assembly as the executing one, you'll need to provide an assembly qualified name (*for example, "NamespaceA.MyClass, MyAssembly"*).

### UPDATE

The OP said in some comment:

> If I do use: public `Singleton<BaseObject>[]` singletons;, it warns me
>   with: 'error CS0309: The type BaseObject' must be convertible to
>   Singleton' in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'Singleton'

This is another problem: you can't do *covariance* in classes. For doing such thing, you'll need an interface like this:

```
public interface ISingleton<out TBaseObject> where TBaseObject : .........
```

And make the `Singleton<T>` class implement it.

Thus, you can create such array this way:

```
public ISingleton<BaseObject>[] singletons;
```

*Covariance* lets you upcast generic parameters and it's limited to interfaces and delegates.

Learn more here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: or you can use `typeof(Singleton<>)`, but  I think it's not that he actually wants

Comment: Do not use `Type.GetType()` here.

Comment: The reflection approach sounds good. So, if I want to define an array of those singletons, how should I do that? (something like `public Singleton<>[] singletons`)

Comment: If I do use: `public Singleton<BaseObject>[] singletons;`, it warns me with: `'error CS0309: The type `BaseObject' must be convertible to `Singleton<BaseObject>' in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Singleton<T>'`

Comment: @llyaivanov Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my answer to reflect it!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer working with interfaces solved the problem. Also, was nice to discover some more generic related stuff. Very interesting!